# Jackson @JsonPropertyOrder ignored in version 2.8.6

Tags: serialization, properties, jackson

In Jackson 2.8.6 neither `@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true)` nor

`@JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"status", "extraCost", "liability", "advice", "clause"})`

..have any effect on how my Java object is serialized.

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true)
class MyPremium {
  private String status;
  private BigDecimal extraCost = BigDecimal.ZERO;
  private Premium liability = new Premium();    
  private String advice;
  private List<String> clause;

  // getters and setters omitted
}
```

With every application restart the order of the properties in the serialized output changes.

Any idea what could be the problem? The documentation is rather vague. It suggests it doesn't work for JSON, but then again I see many [examples](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) of this annotation successfully ordering JSON properties.

> This annotation may or may not have effect on deserialization: for
>   basic JSON handling there is no effect, but for other supported data
>   types (or structural conventions) there may be.
>
> NOTE: annotation is allowed for properties, starting with 2.4, mostly
>   to support alphabetic ordering of Map entries.
>
> http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.8.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html

Answer (score 1):

Documentation's mention of deserialization is irrelevant here -- you are serializing properties. And annotation should definitely work for Jackson 2.x.

You are not including code you use for serialization, however, so showing it (or explaining what framework is using it if not direct usage) could be helpful.

Other than this, yes, use of annotation like shown should change ordering when writing JSON (or other supported formats). One possibility could be that actual `ObjectMapper` you use came from Jackson 1.x (which has different annotations).
Or, if you are not controlling serialization maybe frameworks is not even using Jackson (some web frameworks default to other json libraries).

Comment: _"One possibility could be that actual ObjectMapper you use came from Jackson 1.x (which has different annotations)"_ that was actually how I encountered this problem, thanks for this tip!